# href attribute with http

Tags: html, href

Normally we would add a link like this

`<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>`

but while reading a book I found like this

`<a href-http://www.stackoverflow.com/>Stackoverflow</a>`

Is this a mistake, if not What are the differences between them and why to use **href="ulr" and href-http: "url**" ?

Comment: Looks more like a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo. That `-` should simply be  a `=`.

Comment: There is no `" " ` even

Comment: @C-Link, the quotation marks are not needed in practice, and this is being made official in HTML5. (By HTML 4 rules, quotation marks are needed here.) So if the book lacks quotation marks, it could either be due to following HTML5 rules, or just an oversight/mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>` is the correct format ;)

As for the second example you provided that actually came out of a textbook, that is a typo and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in real situation the second is incorrect format.

see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fLpk2/

```
<a href-http://www.stackoverflow.com/>Stackoverflow</a>
```

Second user click it but nothing happen that prove it may be textbook has mistake.